# How can I make small grid lines above ChartJS labels?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using Chart.js to draw a simple line chart.
How can I make small grid lines on top of the xAxis labels?

The documentation for Line Chart is here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.3/getting-started/?h=line, but I can't find anything about it.

I removed the XAxis and YAxis grid lines.

This is an example of the small grid lines wanted:
[image: ChartJS area]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the gridlines you can set the `drawOnChartArea` to false:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```